# C# Webclient.UploadFile via specific network adapter

Tags: c#, networking, upload, adapter, webclient

I am writing a WPF control application that uses 3 network adapters:
1. for web access
2. AdHoc PLC communication
3. AdHoc CAB printer support

Printer works as an FTP server that prints labels according to .txt script files sent to a specific folder.
The code I am using is:

```
    try
    {
        string file = FileName;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
            client.UploadFile(Adr + file, "STOR", file);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
```

It all works well if there is no network adapter to connect to web. The moment it is active I cannot upload to printer. My guess is WebClient tries to reach printer via main network connection and doesnt bother to try the specific network adapter the printer is directly connected to.

Is there a way to enforce ulpoad to printers IP address via specific network adapter?

Comment: IP route/configuration should determine this, not physical adapter selection

Comment: Yes, I have fiddled with IP ROUTE with no luck so far. Via tracert I have established that packets are directed via main internet interface. Both internet and printer connection are on 255.255.255.0. I have almost total flexibility as to printer ip config, however keep in mind I am no web guru and may not understand some otherwise trivial concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your web network connection doesn't enforce you to use a proxy. The Network card for were the traffic exits is determined by the network address destination and it's the OS that makes that routing.